# HttpWebRequest: загрузка файлов типа IFormFile

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2

В приложении, развернутом на `http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:3000`, по маршруту `/test` находиться actiоn-метод

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IActionResult Post(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null) return BadRequest("file is null");

    var message = $"File name: {Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName)}\r\n" +
                  $"File length: {file.Length}";
    return Ok(message);
}
```

Как видно, когда в `file (IFormFile)` приходит `null`, то возвращается ошибка 400 с сообщением `file is null` иначе статусный код 200.

Используя приведенный [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36745901/2948684) код, написал метод, для отправке файлов на сервер и пытаюсь отправить файл-изображение по маршруту `uri = http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:3000/test`

```
public void Upload(string uri, string filePath)
{
    string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"{0}\";\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
    string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    byte[] boundarybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            byte[] formbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            requestStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
            int bytesLeft = 0;

            while ((bytesLeft = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesLeft);
            }

        }
    }
```

но в `file (IFormFile)` постоянно приходит `null` и согласно условию возвращается 400 с сообщением

> file is null

**Не понимаю почему так происходит.**

Вот что перехватывает Fiddler

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если заменить

```
request.ContentType = "application/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
```

на

```
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
```

то возвращаеться **401** ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял - вам необходимо указать наименование переменной в которую хотите "положить файл": `name="file"`.

Контент должен выглядеть так:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=\"{0}\";\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n
```